# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header - Node Express

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, spotify

From the front end and through jQuery I am making `GET` requests to a `node/express` app. This app then speaks to the spotify API to authenticate a user. I am getting the following error message when I try and make a call to the `presave` endpoint.

> :8000/#access_token=AccessTokenProvidedBySpotify
>   XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://XXX.XX.XXX.XXX/presave. Response to preflight
>   request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://XXX.XX.XXX.XXX:8000' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

I have tried adding the following code to my `app.js` express app, but it didn't work. I tried everything else i could find online too, but cannot get it working.

```
var app = express();
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

app.get('/presave', function(req, res){
    var options = {
        url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
        },
        json: true
    };

    requestPromise(options).then(function(body) {
        userEmail = body.email;
        userId = body.id;
        var optionsTwo = {
            url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/' + userId + '/playlists',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
            },
            json: true
        };
        return rp(optionsTwo).then(function (body) {
            playlists = body.items;
            res.json(playlists);
        });
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err)
    })
});
```

**EDIT**

I have also implemented the answer provided below, but this doesn't work either. If I `console.log(req.method)` it is always `GET`, it never shows `OPTIONS`.

```
var app = express();
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    return res.send(200);
  } else {
    return next();
  }
});
```

My front end code looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx/presave',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data)
    }
});
```

Comment: There is a small typo in this line: `app.get('/presave', function(req, res){]`. Redundant `]` at the end.

Comment: @SphDev sorry, typo, its not like that in my code

Comment: you're not responding to preflight requests, as the error suggests.

Comment: @KevinB ok, any guidance as to how this error can be eradicated?

Comment: Here is a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298745/how-do-i-send-a-cross-domain-post-request-via-javascript)

Comment: Yes, respond to the preflight request. Currently it's just timing out or getting 404

Comment: @KevinB is it timing out? The error message shows in the console immediately

Comment: That would suggest you have proper express error handling, which is ending the request that wasn't responded to.

Comment: @KevinB ah ok, thanks very much. Do you have a link to somewhere explaining how to respond to the preflight request in express correctly? The link above is a bit more php focussed

Comment: well, you respond to a get request using app.get, how would you respond to an options request?

Comment: `app.options`? :-)

Comment: indeed. it's no different, other than the response should be empty.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129647/discussion-between-phantom-and-kevin-b).

Comment: so should it just be `app.options()`? what should go inside there?

Comment: respond with a 200 status code. what else

Comment: @KevinB i have implemented the code in the answer below, but it still doesn't work.  When I check `console.log(req.method)` it is always a `GET` request. It never says `OPTIONS`

Comment: Then are you still getting a CORS error? what specifically does it say?

Answer (score 1):

The error message "preflight request doesn't pass access control check" says the failure was caused by the preflight request rather than the post request. So you need to let the prerlight request passes.

```
var app = express();
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    return res.send(200);
  } else {
    return next();
  }
});

app.get('/presave', function(req, res){
   res.send('here');
});
```

On the front end side, the ajax call should use GET

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx/presave',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data)
    }
});
```

Comment: I have no idea why, as this looks like it should work, but I am still getting the same error. When I check `console.log(req.method)` it is always a `GET` request. It never says `OPTIONS`

Comment: the type of your ajax call should be `Get`. I updated my answer

Comment: Apologies, it was `GET` in my jQuery code. This is not the issue, this looks like a real tricky one to figure out

Comment: I see you updated the ajax to use `Get`. However, you also updated the app to use `post` at the express side. which one is the correct one? Also, is the CROS error thrown by express, or when you are making request to `https://api.spotify.com/v1/me` ?

Comment: sorry man, it should be `app.get` too. I changed the code a bit to simplify the example a bit at the start, but now its all the same as i have. That is one thing, I am not entirely sure if the CORS error is express or the request to spotify. I believe that it is `express` but as none of these solutions are working perhaps it is spotify. I would have thought that i would have seen something online, and that it would be more common if it was spotift?

Comment: Just for testing, can you try w/ `app.get('/presave', function(req, res){
   res.send('here');
});` to see if the error is from your side or from spotify side?

Comment: will check it tomorrow when I have the code in front of me again! Thanks for all your help

Comment: looks like it never hits that route as. Just before it does it gives the error message, and in my console it never shows `'getting here'`, as I did `console.log('getting here')`. Does this mean it is an issue on my side or spotify? From what I can tell it is not being allowed to hit that route

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129899/discussion-between-phantom-and-anthony-c).